# Use a variable to set visibility of TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF how does one show/hide a TabItem depending on the value of an Int variable by using a style?

**Style Attempted**

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyleVisibility"
       TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TabItemIndex, 
                                           Mode=OneWay,
                                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**TabItem Xaml**:

```
<TabItem Name="Tab1" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyleVisibility}">
```

**Alternate Attempt**

Possibly a Style for each tab (copy/paste) and change the value each time:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TabItemIndex, 
                               Mode=OneWay, 
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                
             Value="1">
</DataTrigger>
```

But it's will not be clean (one style per TabItem).

Is there is a way to define the tabItem visibility depending on the name of the tabItem or depending of an int and have the same style for every TabItem?

Comment: Where is this value coming from? Is it a property in code-behind?

Comment: @MikeEason Yes I want to set a variable in code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter to do that, here's an example on how to do that (untested)

```
class MyConverter : IValueConverter //Implement this one
{
    public object Convert(object state....)
    {
        string name = (string)state;
        if(name == "something") 
          return Visiblity.Visible;
        else return Visibilty.Hidden;
    }
}

<Grid.Resources>
    <myConverterNamespace:MyConverter x:Key = "myConverter"/>
</Grid.Resource>

    <TabItem Name="Tab1" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyleVisibility}" 
Visbility={Binding ElementName="someTabItemName" Path="Name" Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got what I made wrong I was trying to work on visibility, all I had to do was to work on SelectedIndex.

Comment: Are you answering your own question? If so either mark this as the answer (with more explanation) or delete the whole question.